# Best way to display a PDF within an android app

Tags: android, pdf

I am a novice app builder and I have been looking around at the best way to display a PDF from within my android app. So far I have come across methods that look either outdated or extremely convoluted. I have the PDF I wish to display (a short 2 page file) and I would like the user to be able to click a button and display it. If there is a way someone has discovered could they please help me out, it seems like it should be simple. But alas, nothing is ever simple right?

Comment: yeah I looked at that but I was left confused, I will continue to explore. Thank you!